# Multiple columns with counts from one table while using joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to using psql and am interested in using the `count` function on the same table to output several different columns with different counts based on conditions.

My table contains auto rental trips, and the columns would be `short trips`, `trips`, and `avis_trips`.

In my query

```
select TO_CHAR(date_trunc('day', start_time::timestamp),'YYYY-MM-DD')  AS date,
count(*) filter (where distance > 0 and distance < 100) AS short_trips,
count(*) as trips,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM routes INNER JOIN rentals on rentals.id = routes.rental_id 
     WHERE rentals.name = 'Avis 'AND
    routes.start_time::timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) AS avis_trips FROM
routes WHERE
start_time::timestamp <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC
```

This query works and produces the correct result for `short_trips` and `trips`, but does not group Avis trips by `date` - it instead produces a count of all avis trips for each row.

The desired output would look something like this

```
output
        date short_trips trips avis_trips
1 2018-03-10          10    12          1
2 2018-03-09           6    11          2
3 2018-03-08           8    10          1 ...
```

How does one integrate `INNER JOIN` with a separate count column?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please reformat your SQL so we can actually read it.

Comment: I've reformatted the query

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've provided a sample output.  The main question is how to perform a COUNT with a JOIN statement and then apply the same GROUP BY.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your sub-select out to your main query so that you have all the columns you need to filter your counts on. Use a `LEFT JOIN` if not all `routes` have a related `rental`:

```
SELECT
  start_time :: DATE AS date,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE distance > 0 AND distance < 100) AS short_trips,
  count(*) AS trips,
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE r.name = 'Avis') AS avis_trips
FROM routes
  LEFT JOIN rentals r ON r.id = routes.rental_id
WHERE
  routes.start_time <= now()
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I've removed the date fiddling for clarity.